# Group by userid in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have 10 files with the same schema:

user_Id,    time_stamp,    event_type,  descriptions,  other_columns

They are stored in 10 files because they come from 10 different sources.  To do some analysis, I need to group the same user's data (records) together and produce some values (the computing logic is fairly complicated and can not be done by reduceByKey).  So I use groupByKey() in Spark. This is very time-consuming due to shuffle. Any ideas how to make this faster? The computation will be completely within the records with the same user id at this stage.   btw, I can talk to the data provider to ask them to prepare the data in certain format.

Comment: It sounds like you're aware of this, but [`groupByKey` is slow](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html). If you can't use `reduceByKey`, can you use `combineByKey` or `foldByKey` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the same records with the same user id in a partition when you read the file into a RDD. For example, suppose you want to create 20 partitions for the RDD, you can get the hashcode of a user id in a record, and use `hashcode % 20` to assign this record to one of the partitions. It can make sure the records with the same user id go into the same partition.